# FatalErrorException in laravel5

Tags: laravel-5, fatal-error

I am using `laravel 5`, I want to get data from database but it throwing the below error:

> FatalErrorException in LearnController.php line 38: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\DB' not found

I have been added the database details then also i am able get the title from `ads_new` table

Here's my code:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class LearnController extends Controller {

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Home Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller renders your application's "dashboard" for users that
    | are authenticated. Of course, you are free to change or remove the
    | controller as you wish. It is just here to get your app started!
    |
    */

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


    /**
     * Show the application dashboard to the user.
     *
     * @return Response
     */

    public function home()
    {   
        $users = DB::table('ads_new')->get();

        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
            var_dump($user->title);
        }                       
    }    
}
```

database.php

```
<?php

return [

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| PDO Fetch Style
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default, database results will be returned as instances of the PHP
| stdClass object; however, you may desire to retrieve records in an
| array format for simplicity. Here you can tweak the fetch style.
|
*/

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Database Connection Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify which of the database connections below you wish
| to use as your default connection for all database work. Of course
| you may use many connections at once using the Database library.
|
*/

'default' => 'mysql',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Database Connections
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here are each of the database connections setup for your application.
| Of course, examples of configuring each database platform that is
| supported by Laravel is shown below to make development simple.
|
|
| All database work in Laravel is done through the PHP PDO facilities
| so make sure you have the driver for your particular database of
| choice installed on your machine before you begin development.
|
*/

'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlite',
        'database' => storage_path().'/database.sqlite',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'autoclick'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver'   => 'pgsql',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'autoclick'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
        'schema'   => 'public',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'autoclick'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'cluster' => false,

    'default' => [
        'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
        'port'     => 6379,
        'database' => 0,
    ],

  ],

];
```

Comment: Add a \ before DB like so; `\DB` or add `use \DB;` at the top.

Comment: PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: This would be your config within `config/database.php` but your initial problem has been solved.

Comment: thanks matt i got the result but can i know how to  pass all data to view?

Comment: Have a look at the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs)

Comment: THANKS  MATT BURROW LARAVEL5 IS DIFFICULT THAN LARAVEL4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DB` façade is in the global namespace, so you need to import it at the top of your controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
```

Have a read up on namespaces in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) but i used autoclick has database why it showing homestead name has database?

Comment: @demodemo Depends where you specified the database name. Have you put it in your **.env** file? http://laravel.com/docs/master/configuration#environment-configuration

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this solution:

From Matt Burrow comment
Add a \ before DB like so; \DB or add use \DB; at the top.

So it should be like :

```
class LearnController extends Controller {

public function home()
{

$users = \DB::table('ads_new')->get();

    foreach ($users as $user)
    {
    var_dump($user->title);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: check code on app/config/database.php .if database name as laravel.

       'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'laravel',
        'username'  => 'forge',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),